# UML with lots of classes

Tags: uml

in UML Class Diagram i have lots of classes that Implements one Class IComponent.

if I show all the classes together as each class implements IComponent i have to show link between IComponent and Implementing class .

Is there any way that i can Show IComponent with single link that all class in some boundary implements IComponent Interface I created ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286949/how-can-i-simplify-an-uml-class-diagram-inheritance-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "fork" link so that only one link exists from the IComponent class, as is shown [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html?cid=28)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect some classes with the IComponent class and add to these connections the following constraint - {incomplete}.